# Pass data to two Containers Views not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, containers, segue

I have a master view with 2 containers first for collection view and the second for table view, the collection & the table using same data array from master view.
I want to toggle between them in master view and have button to filter this array and pass the new data to containers.

[image]

In master view i used segue to pass data, but it does not work!

```
NSString *listPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"books" ofType:@"plist"];
dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:listPath];
filteredArray = dataArray;
```

.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"BookCollectionView"]) {
        CollectionViewController *coll = segue.destinationViewController;
        [coll setDataArray:filteredArray];

    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"BookTableView"]) {
        TableViewController *table = segue.destinationViewController;
        [table setDataArray:filteredArray];


    }

}

- (IBAction)filterDataArray:(id)sender
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"book_title contains[cd] %@", @"some text"];
    filteredArray = [dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
```

In both collection & table:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dataArray;
@synthesize dataArray;
```

And used dataArray for data source to collection & table.

I want to pass array and filtered array to containers.
Can anyone help please

Comment: use SharedClass and define your array their ..,so you don't need to pass array all the time and it will be easier

Comment: How can I use SharedClass?

Comment: before doing that pls update your NSArray to  NSMutableArray type..it might work..!!

Comment: Still not working!

Comment: It seem like that your filteredArray does not retain its values. . .  is your filteredArray is a class level object or a property.

Comment: @WissamiOS make sure your filteredArray is also NSMutableArray type..

Comment: It's working, this is from NSLog: filtered array count: 63

Comment: i tried to write this after filtered action :     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BookCollectionView" sender:self.view];
but it showing error

Comment: replace retain with strong in your property may it work . and there is no need for synthesize.

Comment: I did that, still not working

Comment: The question is: when segue pass data? After view did load?!! or when? I tried to init array in view will appear and still no results

Comment: check this https://github.com/mluton/EmbeddedSwapping

Comment: This is not correct I think. For the ContainerView you need another Container scene as the main controller, and that controller is doing all the switching.

Comment: I put 2 ContainerView in same place